# Check Which Program calls a function or procedure Oracle EBS R12(PL/SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

When I submit a concurrent request , A package is getting called and getting executed . How to check , which program or package or procedure is calling that ?

Comment: Please let me know , if the question is not clear enough to provide a solution. Please let me know your questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from the below link

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4471072100346198785

Comment: owa_util.who_called_me is api needs to be used